# TEMP tablespace issue, varied response while executing through package and through individual procedures

Tags: oracle

I've a package which has 15 procedures. While I'm executing the package for a particular parameter say 'x', the package execution fails with error `ORA-01652:Unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP`. at a particular procedure where it is merging into a table which has around 70k rows. But, while I run the package with individual procedures, the package is executing successfully. The particular procedure is executing in 6 minutes while executing individually, but when ran through package, it is taking around 40 minutes and failing.All the previous procedures have `commit` clause, so there is no issue of previous procedure is occupying the temp space. Can you please let me know, what else I can look for to resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by `while I run the package with individual procedures`? May be it better to post some sample code.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin I mean when I am calling package, there is a procedure, which internally calling 10 other procedures of the same package one by one. 
I have several insert/update/merge statements. After each and every procedure, I am doing commit.

But after 5-6 procedures it is failing.

But when I am executing one procedure at a time, manually, it is running fine. Not able to get the reason for the same.

Comment: So the first case is when you call some wrapper procedure and it calls another procedures internally. The second case is when you call these another procedures yourself, one by one. Is it right? And in which case the error occurs, first or second?

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin yeah, you got it right. The second case is running fine without any error

Comment: What about posting the code of procedure which fails? It might give some ideas. And by the way what is your temp segment size?

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin TEMP space  is having  15GB. I cant provide code. Sorry.